# How to write xpath for the following HTML code

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

`<p class="">
<b class="">Inventory:</b> 177<br><b class="">UNIT:(12  per unit)
</b></p>`

I need to get the value 177.

I tried with two xpaths the first one is

`//*[@id='product_addtocart_form']/div[3]/p[2]/text()`,it is throwing an exception invalid selector exception-it should be an element,

and another xpath is `//p/b[1]/text()` it is also throwing the same exception.

Comment: The answer given by @Vignesh Waran locates the text exactly but I don't know why it's not working when I try to locate through selenium locator, it throws the error, So do onething, read the entire in `<p>` and then extract 177 from that. which language are you using? If you are using Ruby, I will update the answer to fetch that value.

Comment: @suvarnareddy As your HTML contains `<p class="">`, can you update the question a bit more of the `outerHTML` till we can identify the `<p>` tag uniquely?

Answer (score 0):

for the tags which you have given,

```
//p/b[contains(.,'Inventory')]/following-sibling::text()[normalize-space()]
```

the above Xpath works.
But, for more accurate Xpath, share the page link to analyse the source code.

Comment: it is throwing an invalid selector exception-it should be an element

Comment: This is amazing one, I have never written like this one, It perfectly works to locate the text 177 but when I tried to pass via selenium code, it throws the error that `The expression is not a legal expression.`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `/text()` part of your xpath, and acquire the text, using SeleniumElement method `getText()` or an equivalent.

Comment: Thank u @Edvins i tried like that but i am getting the result as "inventory:" only not that value ,is there any other way

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this relative Xpath :

```
//*[@class='Your Class name']//*[text()='177']
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove  /text() from your xpath, and acquire the text, using SeleniumElement method getText() or an equivalent. It will give the text value of only html bold tag. 
In which html tag deos text 117 belong ?